# Tapping into Rails logger from Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a single ruby file which runs in parallel to my rails application, listens to a RabbitMQ queue and updates objects from the model when it receives a message:

```
require "bunny"
require 'json'
require 'rubygems'
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)

Rails.logger.info "MQ Host: " + Rails.application.config.mq_host
Rails.logger.info "MQ Username: " + Rails.application.config.mq_username

conn = Bunny.new(automatically_recover: false,
                 hostname: Rails.application.config.mq_host,
                 user: Rails.application.config.mq_username,
                 password: Rails.application.config.mq_password)
conn.start

ch = conn.create_channel
q = ch.queue(Rails.application.config.mq_queue,
             durable: Rails.application.config.mq_durable)

begin
  puts " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"
  q.subscribe(block: true, manual_ack: true) do |delivery_info, properties, body|
    # do stuff
end
```

It's run like this:

```
bundle exec ruby -rubygems bin/recv.rb
```

It reads the config from the Rails app and loads, modifies and saves models just fine. What I can't get it to do is log to the Rails logger. What I mean is that the messages I'm logging don't appear in the main app logs or as output to the console where the script is executed.

The output from:

```
puts "Logger path: #{Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logdev).dev.path}"
puts "Rails env: #{ENV['RAILS_ENV']} / #{Rails.env}"
```

is

```
Logger path: .../log/development.log
Rails env:  / development
```

as you might expect.

Can anyone tell me why I'm not seeing the log messages?

Comment: Can you please check your log level? Or try using `Rails.logger.error`

Comment: Thanks, I tried using Rails.logger.error and there was no change.